# Connected component reads from Redux store, but action creators don't update it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I've got a connected component that gets information from the Redux store and displays it onscreen. But whenever I try and dispatch an action to update the state, it doesn't end up doing anything:

`AppSettings.js`

```js
import {
  MINUTE_MS,
  MINUTE_S,
} from '../constants'
import {
  decrementSession,
  incrementSession,
} from './timerSlice'

import React from 'react'
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import equal from 'fast-deep-equal'

/* eslint-disable no-useless-constructor */

export class AppSettings extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = {
      sessionLength: this.props.sessionLength,
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (!equal(this.props, prevProps)) {
      this.setState((_, props) => {
        return {
          sessionLength: props.sessionLength,
        };
      })
    }
  }

  render() {
    let sessionLength = Math.floor(this.props.sessionLength / MINUTE_MS) % MINUTE_S
    sessionLength = ('0' + sessionLength).slice(-2)
    
    return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <h3>
            session
          </h3>
          <button 
            id='sessionUp'
            onClick={this.props.incrementSession}
            >
            up
          </button>
          <h4>
            {sessionLength}
          </h4>
          <button 
            id='sessionDown'
            onClick={this.props.decrementSession}
            >
            down
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    sessionLength: state['sessionLength'],
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps() {
  return {
    decrementSession,
    incrementSession,
  };
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps,
)(AppSettings)
```

`timerSlice.js`

```js
import {
  DEFAULT_SESSION,
  MINUTE_MS,
} from '../constants'

import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const timerSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'timer',
  initialState: {
    sessionLength: DEFAULT_SESSION,
  },
  reducers: {
    decrementSession(state) {
      state['sessionLength'] -= MINUTE_MS
    },
    incrementSession(state) {
      state['sessionLength'] += MINUTE_MS
    },
  }
})

export const {
  decrementSession,
  incrementSession,
} = timerSlice.actions

export default timerSlice.reducer
```

`store.js`

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import reducer from '../features/timerSlice'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducer
})

export default store
```

Upon initial render, the component reads from the store just fine, and displays the appropriate value. Unit testing showed that the component updates the value rendered onscreen when it's passed new props. My unit test also shows that the appropriate functions are called whenever buttons are pressed. I ran my app in the browser, and it showed that the Redux store wasn't being updated at all.

How come my store isn't responding whenever I try and dispatch actions from my component?

Comment: Do you have the redux-devtools (browser extension) installed? Can you verify your store is at least registering the action was dispatched? It conveniently allows you to dispatch actions right from the dev tool, BTW. If you see the action logged then check the action payload, if any, and the state diff.

Comment: @DrewReese Turns out that the store wasn't registering that the action was dispatched. When I use redux-devtools to manually dispatch an action of type `timer/incrementSession`, it registers the change, but not when I click any of the buttons on my app. What do you suggest in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something seems to be wrong with `mapDispatchToProps` in the current setup.  I got it working by converting it to a function component and using `useDispatch` to call the actions.

The local state is unnecessary.  Just use the value selected from redux directly.

```
export const AppSettings = () => {

  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const sessionLength = useSelector(state => state.sessionLength);

  const seconds = Math.floor(sessionLength / MINUTE_MS) % MINUTE_S
  const secondsString = ('0' + seconds).slice(-2)
  
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <h3>
          session
        </h3>
        <button 
          id='sessionUp'
          onClick={() => dispatch(incrementSession())}
          >
          up
        </button>
        <h4>
          {secondsString}
        </h4>
        <button 
          id='sessionDown'
          onClick={() => dispatch(decrementSession())}
          >
          down
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[Code Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-64615804-mozkm?file=/src/App.tsx)

Comment: It *should* be working with the object shorthand notation though. The only scenario I could think of where the object shorthand would fail is if there was a circular import and `incrementSession` & `decrementSession` were `undefined` at initial run and available only later. So maye looking for circular imports could help find the root problem.

Comment: @phry I don't think circular imports were the problem either. When I just stopped using `mapDispatchToProps` and used the `this.props.dispatch()` method that comes default with connected components, it worked fine with `incrementSession` and `decrementSession`.

Comment: @phry I started playing with it using mapDispatchToProps with everything in the same file.  I honestly have no idea why it wasn’t working because it looked right to me.  But I can confirm that it was not working.

Comment: @jaime that would not speak against a circular dependency. The point with a circular dependency is that something circular imported may be `undefined` on the initial evaluation of code (when defining your `mapStateToProps` object), but referencable later, e.g. in a method call from your component.
But going by what @LindaPaiste said, that was probably not it. Mysterious!